# Arbitrary phase in unitary transformation of quasiparticle operators?

Tags: condensed-matter, superconductivity, second-quantization

I am working in the context of condensed matter, if that is important. See my other recent question [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/725264/where-do-arbitrary-phases-of-wavefunctions-go-under-second-quantization), and [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/534630/fermion-operators-why-rm-su2-symmetry-and-not-rm-u2-symmetry) which seems related. For more context, I am working with a superconducting ($s$-wave) Hamiltonian, but only diagonalizing the single-electron (non-superconducting) part of the Hamiltonian. After diagonalizing the single-electron part, I use the diagonalized operators for the full Hamiltonian (which has pairing terms with $c_\downarrow c_\uparrow$ and $c^\dagger_\uparrow c^\dagger_\downarrow$).

If you have a unitary transformation,

$$ \begin{pmatrix} f^\dagger_{+} \\ f^\dagger_{-} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b^* & a^* \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} c^\dagger_{\uparrow} \\ c^\dagger_{\downarrow} \end{pmatrix},
$$
with $|a|^2+|b|^2=1$, which diagonalizes a (complex) Hamiltonian, is there an overall indeterminacy in phase factor of $a$ and $b$? I.e., we have

$$ H = \begin{pmatrix} f^\dagger_{+} & f^\dagger_{-} \end{pmatrix}
       \begin{pmatrix} E_+ & 0 \\ 0 & E_- \end{pmatrix}
       \begin{pmatrix} f_{+} \\ f_{-} \end{pmatrix} \\
     = \begin{pmatrix} c^\dagger_{\uparrow} & c^\dagger_{\downarrow} \end{pmatrix}
       \begin{pmatrix} |a|^2E_+ + |b|^2E_- & ab^*(E_+-E_-) \\ a^*b(E_+-E_-) & |b|^2E_+ + |a|^2E_- \end{pmatrix}
       \begin{pmatrix} c_{\uparrow} \\ c_{\downarrow} \end{pmatrix},
$$
so that only the phase of $ab^*$ seems to matter, not the individual phases of $a$ and $b$, and we have (if the off-diagonal parts of the Hamiltonian are imaginary)

$$ a = e^{i\phi} |a|,\ \ \ \ \  b = i e^{i\phi}|b|,$$

where $\phi$ is completely arbitrary. My question is, can $\phi$ really be taken as completely arbitrary, or is there some reason one must take, say, $\phi=0$?

I have followed a [paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.aop.2009.11.003) doing this same thing, and they implicitly took $\phi=0$ without mentioning it, but I don't know whether this was done out of necessity or convenience (their result, as far as I can tell, wouldn't depend on $\phi$).

Comment: Preprint: https://arxiv.org/abs/0910.4763

Comment: Your Hamiltonian $H$ is invariant under $f\rightarrow e^{i\phi}f$, so there is no preference for the overall phase.